# Ajustar pantalla automático con codigo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quisiera saber si hay forma que con html le de el tamaño de la pagina y esta siempre sea esa al entrar

Ejemplo, hice una pagina pero no me di cuenta que estaba 90% y ahora cuando se abre en otro navegador por default esta en 100%, no teniendo la estética esperada al menos que reduzcas el tamaño manualmente
¿hay alguna forma que siempre este en 90% desde cualquier navegador?

Comment: Prueba agregando `style="width: 90%;"` en el elemento `<body>`

Answer (score 2):

Sí, pero lo que estás preguntando puede considerarse una mala práctica, deberías intentar corregirlo primero. De todas formas, respondiendo a tu pregunta: hay una forma de establecer el tamaño de una página web utilizando el elemento  en la sección  de la página. Puedes usar el atributo viewport para establecer el ancho y alto de la página. Por ejemplo:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9">
```

Este código establecerá el ancho de la página en el ancho del dispositivo en el que se está visualizando y la escala inicial en 0.9, lo que significa que la página se mostrará al 90% de su tamaño original. Ten en cuenta que esto solo funcionará en dispositivos móviles, ya que los navegadores de escritorio no utilizan el atributo viewport.

Si desea establecer el tamaño de la página en todos los dispositivos, incluidos los navegadores de escritorio, puedes hacerlo utilizando CSS. Por ejemplo, puede agregar el siguiente código a su hoja de estilos para establecer el tamaño de la página en el 90% de su tamaño original:

```
body {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Ten en cuenta que esto puede afectar la forma en que se muestran otros elementos en la página, así que puede ser necesario ajustar otros estilos en consecuencia.

Espero que esto ayude.